# convert date to xml type date ('YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS)

Tags: date

the user enters date in mm-dd-yy format. I have to convert this into ('YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS) how can i do this in vb.net

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use DateTime Parse or ParseExact methods (or their Try... variation)

then ToString with your format string the resulting value if it is valid, otherwise tell user to enter a better value.

I don't actually speak VBian so I can't provide sample code.